# External Mouse Cursor randomly freezing on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Tags: 18.04, mouse, touchpad, bluetooth

Around 1 month ago I was forced to buy a new notebook (Asus Zenbook UX331UN) and decided to roll with Ubuntu 18.04 LTS in dual-boot with Windows 10. At first everything seemed to work fine, but after a while I noticed a strange behavior:

- When I'm using my external mouse and keyboard (Logitech, connected
  via bluetooth-sender plugged into a USB slot) the mouse pointer
  randomly freezes around every 5 mins. The touchpad on the notebook is
  still working without any problems and so is the keyboard (which
  means the bluetooth connection is still alive). This problem occurs
  more often if I switch windows (e.g. between Firefox and VS Code) and
  some expensive background-task is running. I already searched for
  hours online for any similar problems, but could not find anything.
- In rare cases the clicks from the touchpad also seem to become
  disabled (which means that the cursor is moving but you cannot click 
  anything on the UI). I suspect that this may have the same root cause
  as the problem above.

I used the same external mouse / keyboard with my previous notebook running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS without any problems of that kind.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

My mouse didn't work after upgrading to Ubuntu 18.04.

The origin of the problem was the mouse emulation in Tweaks which was switched on.
Remove the emulation with:

> Tweaks -> Keyboard and mouse -> Remove mouse click emulation

and

> Activities -> Search -> Optimizations -> Keyboard and mouse -> Disable mouse click emulation